# Azure Web Job - How to connect to an Azure MS SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a MVC website that gets published to Azure where it uses an Azure SQL Database.

The time has come where we need to run a scheduled task to send SMS reminders. I was under the impression that Azure Web Jobs was a good fit for this but am having some issues getting it up and running.

I have added a console app to my website solution and referenced by EF data model from the console app (which I would like to publish as a web job).

The current console app looks as follows:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    public static void ProcessNotifications()
    {
        var uow = new KirkleesDatabase.DAL.UnitOfWork();
        uow.CommunicationRepository.SendPALSAppointmentReminders();
    }

}
```

Running the console app will then throw the exception:

> Additional information: User account connection string is missing. This can be set via the 'AzureJobsData' connection string or via the constructor.

This suggests that the Web Job is specifically looking for a connection string that points at a storage account. However, I would like the web job to query an Azure database rather than work with storage.

Is this doable?

Thanks,

Comment: the error message suggests that the WebJob is looking for a storage account connection string for *triggers only*.  Accessing .NET SQL APIs for storage within a WebJob is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Database access from a WebJob in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941001/sql-database-access-from-a-webjob-in-azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the WebJobs SDK does not support SQL databases *as triggers*. For triggers, it only supports Azure Storage (blobs, queues and tables).

You can access Azure SQL Databases from the web job as demonstrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24943522/53236).

Comment: Advice to WebJob newbies. This accepted answer is correct, SQL Database cannot be used as a triggering mechanism to invoke a WebJob handler but routine SQL Database activity within a WebJob handler is ok according to the the response to my SO question on this matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941001/sql-database-access-from-a-webjob-in-azure

Comment: @camelCase - I think the accepted answer should specifically state that, as you said, SQL databases are not supported as *triggers* in the WebJobs sdk.  Someone just reading the answer I think would conclude data SQL database access isn't supported at all in Azure WebJobs.

Comment: @Victor - Please see my comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252226/is-the-azure-webjobs-sdk-specifically-meant-for-working-with-azure-storage#comment39423736_25254916 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252226/is-the-azure-webjobs-sdk-specifically-meant-for-working-with-azure-storage#comment39423952_25254916.  I think your response and Amit's responses are confusing and should be modified.

Answer (score 2):

As Victor wrote, the sdk events are triggered by blobs, queues and tables.
A simple solution for your need: write a console application with a pollig approach. No sdk needed. Details at the beginning of http://blog.amitapple.com/post/73574681678/git-deploy-console-app/

```
while(true)
{
  if ("isthereworktodo?")
  {
    var uow = new KirkleesDatabase.DAL.UnitOfWork();
    uow.CommunicationRepository.SendPALSAppointmentReminders();
  }
  Thread.Sleep(10000);  // set an appropriate sleep interval
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a web job you don't have to use the webjobs sdk, you can use several types of executables (.exe, .cmd, .js, .php, .py, ...).

Try using this new visual studio add-on: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4824551-2660-4afa-aba1-1fcc1673c3d0, follow the steps there to link between your web application and your console application which will be deployed as a webjob when published to your Azure site.